# Flex: How to call a actionscript source path from library project?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, swc

In flex created a SWC file. It has a Actionscript folder which contains the actionscript files. And then created a desktop project in which I want to invoke a actionscript file from SWC.

In normal way we can call the external source file like this

The question is "How can I give a source path or call a external actionscript file from SWC"?

Is it possible to call plain Actionscript and assets(image folder) file path from SWC to new desktop applications after include the lib file into that project?

Comment: `include somepackageinswc.someclass;` doesn't work?

Comment: @ Cherniv: no it doesn't work.

Comment: so first check if there are packages in swc

Comment: yeah checked.. Am able to import the packages from swc to desktop app.

Comment: if you work with FlashDevelop so check its "Add to library" checkbox

Comment: Do your ActionScript files have formal ACtionScript class definitions?  Or just "Stand alone" ActionScript files, such that may be included into a class?  If memory serves me; ActionScript files that don't contain classes may cause compiler errors if you try to put them in a SWC.

Comment: yeah, created a formal actionscript files only under ActionScript folder.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  A formal ActionScript file is one with an as extension.  Is the contents of those ActionScript files an ActionScript class?  Or just a snippet of ActionScript code?

Comment: This is a sample action script file I created in SWC. I want the source path of it to call in the desktop application from SWC.                                    package ActionScript
{
 import flash.filesystem.File;
 .....

 public class HelperClass
 {
  .........
  .......
  applicationType::desktop
  {
   public function window1_initializeHandler():void
   {
   
    Alert.show("Desktop Apps....");
   }
    
  }
  applicationType::web
  {
   public function window1_initializeHandler():void
   {
    
    Alert.show("Web Apps....");
   }
   
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First Create Actionscript class in Library project.
2. Within a class create a instance of class statically, to access it from outside from the class.

   ```
    public class ImagesClass
    {
      private static var iconClass: ImagesClass

      public static function getInstance() : ImagesClass
      {
         if ( iconClass== null )
           iconClass= new ImagesClass();
        return iconClass;
      }
      [Bindable]
      [Embed(source="/assets/player_play.png")]
      public var PlayPause_Play:Class;

      public function ImagesClass()
      {
      }
      public function displayAlert()
      {
           Alert.show("Function Called","Info");
      }
     }
   ```
3. You can call this class from your web/desktop application.
   (eg):in main.mxml

   `<s:Button id="btnLocalVideo" 
              icon="{ImagesClass.getInstance().PlayPause_Pla}" 
          width="100%" 
          height="100%" 
          click="ImagesClass.getInstance().displayAlert()"/>`

like that you can access library project actionscript function/variables. and also icons.